# How to click on a link in div

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Could any one please help me in clicking  the link (Images1) under a div?

```html
<div class="test1"><a class="k1">Images1</a></div>

<div class="test1"><a class="k1">Images2</a></div>
```

Note: Not working

```
var imagesLink = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("k1"))[0];
imagesLink.Click();
```

I am getting an error:

> **{Error "Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results."}**

Comment: Can you share the webpage you are testing if it is not confidential so that we can debug the issue?

Comment: For getting the same Scenario:
(a).Open Google search page, now enter  “Testing “ text in search text page.
(b).Google will show search result page, on result page clicks on “Images” link.
(c). Here you can see inspect element of “Images”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if your page is in an iframe, you need to switch to the frame first.

Given the html from comment as below:

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="hdtb" role="navigation">
            <div id="hdtbSum">
                <div id="hdtb_msb">
                    <div class="hdtb_mitem hdtb_msel"> </div>
                    <div class="hdtb_mitem"> <a class="q qs" href="yahoo.co.in">Yahoo</a> </div>
                    <div class="hdtb_mitem"><a class="q qs" href="gmail.com">Gmail</a></div>
                    <div class="hdtb_mitem"><a class="q qs" href="hotmail.com">Hotmail</a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Multiple ways of finding the Gmail link:

```c#
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".hdtb_mitem > a[href='gmail.com']")).Click();
// alternatives:
// driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".hdtb_mitem > a"))[1].Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='hdtb_mitem']/a[@href='gmail.com']")).Click();
// alternatives:
// driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='hdtb_mitem']/a[text()='Gmail']")).Click();
// driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='hdtb_mitem']/a"))[1].Click();
// driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//div[@class='hdtb_mitem']/a)[2]")).Click();
```

Comment: @DeepaSamota: Then please post the post the real dom, the google image scenario won't help you clarify. Is your site in an iframe? And what's not working? Still the same exception or what?

Comment: I can not post real site URL.I am not getting error but result is not correct. Now second option from search box is selected. Site is not in iframe.

Comment: @DeepaSamota: You can just post the relevant DOM snippet here. If you are just having locators issues, no one's gonna without source. The code above works fine with the html you have provided.

Comment: code is : <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hdtb" role="navigation">
<div id="hdtbSum">
<div id="hdtb_msb">
<div class="hdtb_mitem hdtb_msel">
</div>
  <div class="hdtb_mitem">
  <a class="q qs" href="http://www.yahoo.co.in">Yahoo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hdtb_mitem"><a class="q qs" href="http://www.gmail.com">Gmail</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hdtb_mitem"><a class="q qs" href="http://www.hotmail.com">Hotmail</a>
  </div>
</div></div></div></div>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

ANother XPath approach would be to search 'by text' as the contained text appears to be the only truly unique identifier (this is generally not ideal, but it appears you don't have control of the HTML in this case).

```java
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='test1']/a[contains(text(), 'Images2')]")).Click();
```

Comment: *Not working* can mean many things. Did the error disappear? What **did** happen?

Comment: How is the result not correct? Is the click occurring with no navigation? If so, try click the parent div and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

IWebElement elment = driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Click"));
element.Click();